# Vimeo API not returning a full page of results

Tags: vimeo-api

I'm using the Vimeo API to get paged data on my videos. I'm using the **per_page** and **page** parameters like so:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?page=4&per_page=8
```

However, some of the pages of results do not contain 8 videos. For example my 4th page of results is only returning 6 results, yet page 5 has a full set, and there's many more pages. So it's not like I've ran out of videos.

I've checked the video's privacy settings and can't see any differences between the videos that are showing and the videos I'd expect to show on that page that aren't. I've tried setting a sort direction and that didn't help. I've also used the **query** parameter to search for the videos I think are not showing at they are being returned if I seach for them directly.

Also my auth token scope includes **Public**, **Private** and **Video Files**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in contact with Vimeo support. It's due to an issue on their and they have told me they are releasing a fix on the 21st of Feb 2023. In the meantime adding this parameter to the request is a workaround but this will be removed soon.

```
&include_disabled_by_min_tier=true
```